# ACR terminology

Tags: terminology

Can someone recommend a guide (or a sensical glossary) that would pull together all the terminology used in the Adobe Camera Raw, preferably by tab (Basic, Tone Curve, Detail, etc.), with all the terms/levers that appear and what they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High level I would use the Adobe help files, for an in depth description of each feature I would use a text, and for the best hands on learning I would use videos.

I would read the Adobe Camera Raw help files available online such as:

- [Creative Suite / Introduction to Camera Raw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSBD0EDB3C-9472-48d2-A3B1-7C06FABF0A2B.html)
- [Creative Suite / Camera Raw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSD040CF04-C176-4ecb-8A8E-155FBA26AA77.html)
- [Camera Raw Dialog Box Overview](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSBD0EDB3C-9472-48d2-A3B1-7C06FABF0A2B.html#WS1090C4C6-5EC4-4f24-91AE-ACD46BEC73A5)

If you need more in depth info you would likely be best off using a text such as:

- [Adobe Camera Raw for Digital Photographers Only](http://books.google.com/books?id=wIAgYAdzN8gC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=adobe%20camera%20raw%20Split%20Toning%20tab%20overview&source=bl&ots=vwWcICcK-s&sig=ZBQieldJ-sUFlXbvFfrTlXO4TRI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aq3LUam3I-m4yAGz3YGYCw&ved=0CHgQ6AEwCQ)

Alternatively basically all of these features are well explained in videos that can be easily found:

- [Adobe Camera RAW Adjustment Video Tutorial – Split Toning](http://www.digitalterrain.info/post-processing/adobe-camera-raw-tutes/adobe-camera-raw-adjustment-video-tutorial-split-toning)